# My B1/B2 Visa will expire

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

My B1/B2 visa expires on 23 November 2018, and I have to stay in the US up to 2 December 2018. As I heard while I entered the USA they will grant me a 6 months visa. 
My one off friend with the same B1/B2 visa; his will expire in two days but he got a 6 months visa on arrival in USA. 
Does the same rule and law still apply now?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly do you want to know? It would probably be helpful to know your nationality.

Comment: @Traveller the rules for travel with B visas do not depend on nationality.  Only the rules that govern whether one needs a B visa depend on that.  Once we know that someone has a B visa that's pretty much all the information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The expiry date on US visas work differently from many other countries. The visa only needs to be valid on the day you *enter* the USA. *After* you have entered, your permission to *stay* is governed by the separate "admitted until" date you will get at the border. This date has nothing to do with the expiry of the *visa*, and can routinely be after the visa has expired.

Comment: +1 That is correct. The truth however is that when you are entering on the last days of your visa and come from a less developed country, you will be scrutinized thoroughly. I speak from experience and knowledge within my own circles.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen perhaps it would be helpful to post an answer discussing that. What is the nature of the scrutiny? To what extent is the chance of refused entry reduced compared to that for the same traveler arriving near the beginning of the visa's period of validity?

Comment: @phoog Secondary inspection sometimes like I had or at least more intrusive questioning than is normal. In my case I was detained for 30 minutes although they never questioned me during detention and then abruptly said I could leave. That was during my visiting days using a visa.